# How to split and combine large tar ball file?

Tags: bash, backup, tar

I have this code to split large backup files into smaller chunks that can be saved on the FAT32 filesystem.

```
split -b $(echo "6*(2^30)-1" | bc) --verbose $1/jcubic.tar.gz $1/jcubic.tar.gz-
```

I have the chunks when I want to combine them into a bigger file I have this error:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I use `cat jcubic.tar.gz-* > jcubic.tar.gz` my chunks have 29,7GB in total but the output file has 54.1GB. I have no idea why.

What is the proper way to split the file and combine it into one?

**EDIT:**

```bash
$ echo jcubic.tar.gz-*
jcubic.tar.gz-aa jcubic.tar.gz-ab jcubic.tar.gz-ac jcubic.tar.gz-ad 
jcubic.tar.gz-ae jcubic.tar.gz-af jcubic.tar.gz-ag jcubic.tar.gz-ah
```

**EDIT2**:

I've used Ext4 portion and created 6GB chunks:

```
$ split -b $(echo "6*(2^30)-1" | bc) --verbose jcubic.tar.gz jcubic.tar.gz-
```

Both the input and the chunks have 42.3GB

```bash
$ $ ls -lsh
 43G -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  43G 05-18 23:09 jcubic.tar.gz
6,1G -rw-r--r--. 1 kuba kuba 6,0G 05-21 19:19 jcubic.tar.gz-aa
6,1G -rw-r--r--. 1 kuba kuba 6,0G 05-21 19:20 jcubic.tar.gz-ab
6,1G -rw-r--r--. 1 kuba kuba 6,0G 05-21 19:21 jcubic.tar.gz-ac
6,1G -rw-r--r--. 1 kuba kuba 6,0G 05-21 19:22 jcubic.tar.gz-ad
6,1G -rw-r--r--. 1 kuba kuba 6,0G 05-21 19:23 jcubic.tar.gz-ae
6,1G -rw-r--r--. 1 kuba kuba 6,0G 05-21 19:24 jcubic.tar.gz-af
6,1G -rw-r--r--. 1 kuba kuba 6,0G 05-21 19:25 jcubic.tar.gz-ag
311M -rw-r--r--. 1 kuba kuba 311M 05-21 19:25 jcubic.tar.gz-ah
```

but when using cat:

```bash
cat jcubic.tar.gz-* ~/xxx/jcubic.tar.gz
```

I've got 77GB file that is not tar ball:

```bash
$ file jcubic.tar.gz
jcubic.tar.gz: data
$ ls -lh jcubic.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 kuba kuba 77G 05-21 20:15 jcubic.tar.gz
$ tar xzvf jcubic.tar.gz 
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: Please add output of `echo jcubic.tar.gz-*` to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus added the output of that command.

Comment: Please add output of `file /path/to/jcubic.tar.gz` and the command that issued the above error message (3 lines) to your question.

Comment: The thing is that the gzip error message you're getting is emitted when the file doesn't even *start* like a gzip file. Does `gzip -d jcubic.tar.gz-aa > /dev/null` suffer the same problem or just error out when it comes the unexpected end of stream?

Comment: Btw, since this sounds like you'd be a bit better off if you used a compressor with higher compression (so, instead of `tar czf jcubic.tar.gz allthefiles`, you could `tar cf - allthefiles | zstd -12 | split -b $(( 2**31-1 )) jcubic.tar.zst-split`

Comment: Oh and you're splitting into 6GB-1B sized fragments. Fat32 can't even deal with files that size. You should be getting errors when trying 6GB to FAT32.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for pointing this out, I'm testing using my Linux partition to split and cat the output. I was having an error about filesize when it was above 8GB I think.

Comment: @MarcusMüller `gzip -d jcubic.tar.gz-aa > /dev/null` returned an error about an invalid suffix, but I was able to unpack part of the file when using tar (I've forgotten that I need to cat all the files and used `tar xzvf jcubic.tar.gz-*`).

Comment: I've had problems doing stuff like that using the Danish locale, that thinks "aa" is the letter "å" (it also exists in a few other languages) and sorts it as such, so I often use the `-d` option to `split`. As you mention the unexpected size, I think something else must be at play here, can you add the output of `ls -l` to the question?

Comment: Thanks all for you help it was silly mistake, but maybe it will be helpful to somebody that make same silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake, my `cat` was an alias to `bat`. I rarely use it so I didn't notice.

Using:

```bash
env cat jcubic.tar.gz-* > jcubic.tar.gz
```

solved the issue.

A 6GB file on FAT32 is fine, I could extract the file from my USB hard drive that has FAT32 without issue.

Comment: If your filesystem supports files larger than (4G-1)B, it's definitely not FAT32! That's just a fact - the file size field in a FAT32 entry is 4 B long, so at most 2³²-1 bytes, which is 4 GB-1B. Maybe you have exfat instead of fat32?

Comment: @MarcusMüller maybe, it is the default filesystem that was included when I buy the USB hard drive. I just assume it's Fat32 because this is what I was using when sharing files between Windows and Linux. Just reading the Wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT You're must be right. What is the max size of files on ExFat? I'm not able to find it on Wikipedia.

Comment: On exfat, the maximum file size should be 128 Petabyte in theory. In practice, I'd expect half a Petabyte to work, because cluster sizes don't scale arbitrarily.